# C# how to call this method properly within Next generation

Tags: c#, conways-game-of-life

Thank you in advance for the help on this I have been struggling all week and my teacher will not respond.

Below you will find my current code for my Conways Game of life, I can not call the method that actually runs the simulation; can you please pick apart my code and help me find the answer.

**You do not have to give me the actual code, just how to get it. I really want to learn this and be able to figure this out by miself in the future, but its due tonight and I have been stuck all week...**

I need to call `CountNeighborsToroidal()` in `NextGeneration()` it needs to run the game thank you.

```
namespace The_Game_of_life
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
      
        bool[,] universe = new bool[30, 30];

        Color gridColor = Color.Black;
        Color cellColor = Color.Gray;

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        int generations = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            timer.Interval = 100; 
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            timer.Enabled = false; 
        }

        // Calculate the next generation of cells
        private void NextGeneration()
        {

            CountNeighborsToroidal(cellRect.X, cellRect.Y);

            // Increment generation count
            generations++;

            // Update status strip generations
            toolStripStatusLabelGenerations.Text = "Generations = " + generations.ToString();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NextGeneration();
        }

        private void graphicsPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
         
            int cellWidth = graphicsPanel1.ClientSize.Width / universe.GetLength(0);
            
            int cellHeight = graphicsPanel1.ClientSize.Height / universe.GetLength(1);
            
            Pen gridPen = new Pen(gridColor, 1);

            Brush cellBrush = new SolidBrush(cellColor);

            
            for (int y = 0; y < universe.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                
                for (int x = 0; x < universe.GetLength(0); x++)
                {
                    
                    Rectangle cellRect = Rectangle.Empty;
                    cellRect.X = x * cellWidth;
                    cellRect.Y = y * cellHeight;
                    cellRect.Width = cellWidth;
                    cellRect.Height = cellHeight;

                    
                    if (universe[x, y] == true)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(cellBrush, cellRect);
                    }

                    
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(gridPen, cellRect.X, cellRect.Y, cellRect.Width, cellRect.Height);
                }
            }

            
            gridPen.Dispose();
            cellBrush.Dispose();
        }

        private void graphicsPanel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
           
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                
                int cellWidth = graphicsPanel1.ClientSize.Width / universe.GetLength(0);
                int cellHeight = graphicsPanel1.ClientSize.Height / universe.GetLength(1);

                int x = e.X / cellWidth;
        
                int y = e.Y / cellHeight;

                universe[x, y] = !universe[x, y];



                graphicsPanel1.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void openToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            if (timer.Enabled)
            {
                timer.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                timer.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < universe.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < universe.GetLength(0); x++)
                {
                    universe[x, y] = false;
                }
            }

            graphicsPanel1.Invalidate();
        }

        private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NextGeneration();
        }

        private int CountNeighborsToroidal(int x, int y)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int xLen = universe.GetLength(0);
            int yLen = universe.GetLength(1);
            for (int yOffset = -1; yOffset <= 1; yOffset++)
            {
                for (int xOffset = -1; xOffset <= 1; xOffset++)
                {
                    int xCheck = x + xOffset;
                    int yCheck = y + yOffset;
                    if ((xCheck - 1 >= 0 && yCheck - 1 > 0) && universe[xCheck - 1, yCheck - 1] == true)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if ((xCheck - 1 >= 0) && universe[xCheck - 1, yCheck] == true)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if ((xCheck - 1 >= 0 && yCheck + 1 < yLen) && universe[xCheck - 1, yCheck + 1] == true)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if ((xCheck - 1 >= 0) && universe[xCheck, yCheck - 1] == true)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if ((xCheck + 1 < yLen) && universe[xCheck, yCheck + 1] == true)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if ((xCheck + 1 < xLen && yCheck - 1 >= 0) && universe[xCheck + 1, yCheck - 1] == true)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if ((xCheck + 1 < xLen) && universe[xCheck + 1, yCheck] == true)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if ((xCheck + 1 < xLen && yCheck + 1 < yLen) && universe[xCheck + 1, yCheck + 1] == true)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (universe[xCheck, yCheck] == true)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem calling the CountNeighborsToroidal function from NextGeneration function. The only problem I see here is that the parameters cellRect.x and cellRect.y aren't defined in this piece of code, so you will always get an error.... Try changing CountNeighborsToroidal(cellRect.X, cellRect.Y); with some random int values and see if it works :

```
 private void NextGeneration()
    {

        CountNeighborsToroidal(22, 12);

        // Increment generation count
        generations++;

        // Update status strip generations
        toolStripStatusLabelGenerations.Text = "Generations = " + generations.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This did not work, thank you for your feed back though

Comment: May you post screenshots of the errors you are getting ?